# How to increase the heading of a "List all category" Menu in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am using Joomla 2.5 and Cloudbase2 template.
In one of my menu , I am using "List all category" blogs. (http://ictforu.com/index.php/Programming/all/)

Issue is that the Listing is not demarcated properly , it looks clumsy. 
I need to increase the Heading and also add a Horizontal line for demarcation.

I tried exploring the code , but I am not sure where to add the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is **very** subjective, but judging by what I can see, you need to adjust your CSS files to your liking as shown below, or add additional CSS classes using the suffix override of the module:

Lines 41, 43, 45
http://ictforu.com/libraries/gantry/css/joomla.css

Lines 9, 70, 218, 
http://ictforu.com/templates/ca_cloudbase2_j25/css/template.css

*Maybe* in Gantry at Lines 9, 66, 67
http://ictforu.com/libraries/gantry/css/gantry.css

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. What I actually want is to increase the Core Java , Ruby, C++ categories which is visible in this page: [link](http://ictforu.com/index.php/Programming/all/) . And also a horizontal line in between them. I guess this must be in some Php code for displaying list of Categories, but not able to find out which part of code to touch. Any help is appreciated. Thanks, Madhusudhan

Comment: Added the lines to change in joomla.css then